# Mapper code processing spaces as well

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am trying to read a record from input file in a mapper in which  I don't want to process those records which has spaces. Unfortunately even the records which has spaces are getting processed. Can you please let me know?

**Code:**

```
  @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("smallData.csv"));
        header = bufferedReader.readLine();
        headerList = header.split(",");
    }

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {

            String line = value.toString();
            String[] args = line.split(",");

            if(headerList.length == args.length && !header.equals(line)) 
            {
            String srcip = args[4];
            String dstip = args[5];
            String scountry = args[20];
            String dcountry = args[22];
            Text sourceIP = new Text();
            Text sourceCountry = new Text();
            Text destIP = new Text();
            Text destCountry= new Text();

            if(!scountry.equals(""))
            {   
                sourceIP.set(srcip);
                sourceCountry.set(scountry);
                context.write(sourceCountry,sourceIP);

           }

            if(!dcountry.equals(""))
             {  
                destIP.set(dstip); 
                destCountry.set(dcountry);
                context.write(destCountry,destIP);
             }
```

Comment: Do you mean you have empty lines in your csv file and you don't want to process them ? of you don't want to process a line that has additional space along with text?

Comment: Fields in my csv file (scountry and dcountry) are empty for some records and I dont want to include them for processing.

Comment: As Mapper reads line by line, you can't skip reading that line, however, you can avoid further processing of that record after splitting it. Once you split the line and obtain a String array, check if those fields are empty and only if they are not empty you can proceed. if this doesn't meet your requirements, There's a complicated way of handling missing fields you can check that once https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2017/07/26/processing-missing-values-with-hadoop/

Comment: "Once you split the line and obtain a String array, check if those fields are empty and only if they are not empty you can proceed. " This is exactly what I am doing .. The String array is been stored into scountry and dcountry respectively and validating those fields for empty, but still its processing those empty values

Comment: can you post the sample csv record, I doubt it has  more than one space, so if you post sample csv records which causing problem it would be easy to answer

Comment: scountry dlongitude dcountry
US 180 
US 180 
JP 180 
DE 126.9996948 KR
CN -73.7436981 US
US -110.3607025 US
US -97 US
US 9 DE
US 180 
US 11.5832977 DE
 104.333313 RU
US 180 
 7.1000061 FR
EU 116.9971924 CN

Comment: I am not sure whether you will be able to make out records

Comment: Try doing this  !dcountry.replaceAll("\\s+","").equals("") and  !scountry.replaceAll("\\s+","").equals("")

Comment: "" 374
"US" 271
"CN" 73
"DE" 46
"EU" 32
"JP" 31
"FR" 22
"KR" 18
"GB" 12
"TW" 7
This is the o/p I am getting but spaces should not be considered

Comment: !dcountry.replaceAll("\\s+","").equals("") and !scountry.replaceAll("\\s+","").equals("").....Its still the same even after using this

Comment: try using isEmpty() method instead of .equals("") , this should work

Comment: I have tried isEmpty() , null everthing but its not working . The same java code works as expected in eclipse but when its been written in map/reduce , the records which has spaces are not getting eliminated. Am I mssing something?